# How to add query to my URL?

Tags: php

Basically what I need to do is simple, but a bit complicated for me:

I have one page called 120.php:

```
<?php
$n = basename(__FILE__);

echo $n;
```

When opening the page will appear text 120.php (name of the file)

What I need to do is copy the file and paste it with another number x99 times:

100-200.php

Instead of copying and pasting one by one, I want to know if there is a way with one php file.

To do something like this:

```
http://mywebsite.com?(number).php
```

Kind of Query.

And when the page goes up he will display the number as I wrote above.

Thanks to @BH7 and @flowtron for the help!:)

Comment: depends on your webserver, on apache RewriteRules would be the solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lily ... saw your message before I left. This code will create a file. Hope this sorts you out :-)

```
<form action="#" method="post">
  Number start:<br>
  <input type="text" name="num_start" value="1">
  <br>
  Number end:<br>
  <input type="text" name="num_end" value="5">
  <br><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 


<?php

try{

    if (isset($_POST['num_start']) && isset($_POST['num_end'])){

        $i = $_POST['num_start'];
        $e = $_POST['num_end'];

        while ($i <= $e){
            echo "<a href='http://mywebsite.com?$i.php'>http://mywebsite.com?$i.php</a><br/>";

            $file_name = $i.'.php';
            $handle = fopen($file_name, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$file_name);
            $data = $i.'.php';
            fwrite($handle, $data);


        $i++;
        }
    }

} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'FAILED: Exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "<br/>";
}
?>
```

JUST UPDATED AGAIN... THIS WILL PLACE TEXT INSIDE EACH FILE NOW.

Comment: Each file will have numb.php inside now too. :-) Hope we got there. sleep for me now.

Comment: Thanks you very much for the help and the investment, I used your last code and it worked fine:)

Comment: I am glad it worked. Feel I let you down by doing your homework for you :-)  at the very least you could press answered :-)